# Trouble converting a Query Syntax LINQ query using a 'not in (subquery)' into Method Syntax

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have a working LINQ query using `query syntax` that I am reworking to use `method syntax` and am having difficulties figuring out how to implement the a SQL `not in (subquery)`-like statement in the `method syntax` version.

Any pointers? Thank you!

**Query Syntax - This works:**

```
Foo = await( 
    from foo in _context.foo
    where foo.pid == PId
    && !DraftStatusExceptionList.Contains(foo.Stat)
    && (foo.Csstat != "UNK" || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(foo.Csstat))

        //Below is the segment that I cannot figure out how to convert to method syntax:
        && !(
                from recursiveJoinFoo in _context.foo
                where recursiveJoinFoo.pid == PId
                select recursiveJoinFoo.fooId
            ).Contains(foo.fooId)

    orderby foo.Sdate, foo.Sdate2, foo.recordlocator
    select foo
).
ToListAsync();
```

**Method Syntax:**

```
Foo = await_context.foo
  .Where(r => r.pid == PId)
  .Where(r => !DraftStatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Stat))
  .Where(r => r.Csstat != "UNK" || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Csstat))

      .Where(//cant figure out the not in (subquery) portion)

  .ToListAsync()
```

Comment: Given you already had working code, this may have been a better fit for codereview as opposed to SO, unless there was some specific reason you couldn't keep the code as it was?

Comment: @user2366842 I think it belongs here as syntax conversion, not improvement. On Code Review, I would ask is a recursive query with `Contains` better than `GroupBy/Count() == 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to call the `.Contains` method on your subquery, just like in the query syntax:

```
Foo = await _context.foo
    .Where(r => r.pid == PId)
    .Where(r => !DraftStatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Stat))
    .Where(r => r.Csstat != "UNK" || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Csstat))
    .Where(r => !_context.foo
        .Where(rr => rr.pid == PId)
        .Select(rr => rr.fooId)
        .Contains(r.fooId))
    .OrderBy(r => r.Sdate)
    .ThenBy(r => r.Sdate2)
    .ThenBy(r => r.recordlocator)
    .ToListAsync();
```

In the last `Where` method call, you're pulling out from the database some `fooIds` that match the condition into a new collection, and then check your main collection's element against it.

Note the new variable name `rr` used in the subquery to distinguish elements in the query and subquery, and the negation of `.Contains` method result.

*Edit*: slight code corrections and adding ordering method calls.

Comment: You need a space after `await`. Also, you need `Contains(r.fooId)` in the subquery.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance! Got it working with your help!